# halt the raspberry when power supply connected but not when GPIO3 is shorted to ground

Tags: pi-3, gpio, pi-4, boot, reboot

For context I am using a raspberry PI3 but in the end might use a PI4 (but docs says they should behave the same).

I changed config.txt to allow my raspberry to wake from a halt state (with GPIO3). But is there a way to differentiate a normal boot with power supply from a boot after a halt ? I want my raspberry to only work when booted with GPIO3.

I've seen that it is possible to run commands in the rc.locale file, could I put "sudo halt" in that file, of will that never allow me to boot ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: You should cite references for your claims (which IMHO are wrong). The Pi3 + Pi4 have a number of major differences. Nothing you can do in config.txt influences GPIO3 reboot (which is built into firmware) although there are (unusual) settings which prevent it from working. GPIO3 **DOES NOT** cause boot it only enables boot if shutdown which can be disabled on Pi4.

Comment: You are right, I sould have said that they seem to behave the same only for what I already Implemented but I don't know if they do for what I am trying to achieve.
And you are also right for GPIO3, I am not booting the PI but rebooting it (after a shutdown command)